# GAE REQUEST_LOG_ID env variable is wrong

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-platform

Using the code below I'm sending an email on error. I'm trying to include a link to the Cloud Console logs in the email but the request ID seems to be wrong about 30% of the time.

If I find the request with the wrong ID it's always almost a perfect match  except the last three characters are `0` (in the Stackdriver console) instead of `101` (returned from the env variable), always the same substitution - is this a bug with cloud console or am I trying to use these IDs wrong?

The code (stripped down version):

```
class ErrorAlertMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if response.status_code == 500:
            logger.info(os.environ.get('REQUEST_LOG_ID'))

            msg = 'Link to logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?' + '&'.join((
                'project=%s' % MY_APP_ID,
                'expandAll=true',
                'filters=request_id:%s' % os.environ.get('REQUEST_LOG_ID'),
                'resource=gae_app',
            ))

            # this is a utility func that simply sends email
            sendemail(ERROR_RECIPIENT, msg)
        return response
```

Note I've also logged the REQUEST_LOG_ID to ensure it's not being encoded or something and the log output matches what shows in the link

Comment: For what it's worth I'm seeing the same issue so I suspect that there is a bug somewhere in Google's infrastructure. I upvoted the question and added a bounty in the hopes of getting an answer. I also complained trough my paid google support account, let's see if that goes somewhere :-)

Comment: Try this field: `advancedFilter=protoPayload.requestId` (not 100% sure how exactly to formulate the entire request yet to check...).

Comment: Hm, interestingly the `filter=request_id:%s` actually maps to `operation.id`, not `protoPayload.requestId` as I would assume (confirmed by converting to advanced filter). I can't, however, find any instances where the two are different. What I've been doing is simply `re.sub('101$', '0', os.environ.get('REQUEST_LOG_ID'))` which has gotten the job done

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `os.environ.get('REQUEST_LOG_ID')`, use `request.environ.get('REQUEST_LOG_ID')`.

It may be possible that `os.environ['REQUEST_LOG_ID']` changes between the start of the current request and the time you access it, but `request.environ['REQUEST_LOG_ID']` should not change once the request is initialized. [The docs state](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice) that if one request ID is greater than another, than it occurred later than the other. This implies that the requestID in the Stackdriver console was generated before the one in your email link. This makes me think that somewhere along the line, `os.environ['REQUEST_LOG_ID']` is being updated from `'....000'` to `'....101'` before you access it, while the copy in `request.environ['REQUEST_LOG_ID']` should remain unchanged.

For more info on the `request.environ`, take a look at the source code in `google.appengine.runtime.request_environment.py`. I haven't really found documentation on that, but that code led me to believe that the `os.environ` is not as safe to access as the `request.environ`.